# Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, entity

пишу приложение WPF с веб сервисом wfc, в веб сервесе модель базы данных entity framework, когда пытаюсь передать запрос из клиента на добавление записи в базу данных выдает ошибку, что нет строки подключения как это исправить?
Клиентская часть на добавление данных

```
    DomainOD Domain = new DomainOD();
    private Person person = new Person();
    public MPC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_SaveClients_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.Names = txt_Name.Text;
        person.Suname = txt_suname.Text;
        person.Age = Convert.ToDouble(txt_Age.Text);
        Domain.SaveClientsInsert(person);
    }
```

методы в службе wfc где и выдает ошибку

```
  private DIMAEntities DomaiConnection;
  public  DomainOD()
    {
        DomaiConnection = new DIMAEntities();
    }
    [OperationContract]
    public void SaveClientsInsert(Person obj)
    {        
        DomaiConnection.People.Add(obj);
        DomaiConnection.SaveChanges();  
    }
```

ошибку выдает в `DomaiConnection.People.Add(obj);`
Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в EntityFramework.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "DIMAEntities" в файле конфигурации приложения.

Comment: Файл конфигурации приложите

Comment: `Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "DIMAEntities"` а она у вас есть?